# Windows Security prevents utorrent from running

Tags: windows, security, bittorrent, utorrent

I have been using utorrent for many years. To my surprise, I found it had disappeared from my computer. After some investigation, I found it had been put into Quarantine by Windows Security. I managed to update permissions, and put the program in as an Allowed Threat. However, I still could not get it to run. When I ran it, a popup came with the message: 7-Zip: Access Denied, and a Windows warning - potentially unwanted program blocked. I just could not find any way to get it running again.

ALSO - separately - I could not connect to sites to download the utorrent or bittorent programs - these sites are flagged as having insecure corrections, and the browser will not allow connections to them - but, given the issue I am having, I dont think it would  help to download and re-install the program.

Comment: Have you installed lately a new version of utorrent? I would suggest to pay attention to these warnings.

Comment: No, I did not install a new version - This is the same version which has been running for years (maybe it self-updates, I am not sure)

Comment: I would suggest moving to another bittorrent client, for example qBittorrent. I don't like these warning messages.

Comment: Older versions of Utorrent had vulnerabilities, update to the latest version.

Comment: Though it's possible to add a file to the exclusion list in Defender so that the file will be ignored in routine scans, utorrent might still trigger quarantining when run, should it perform an operation considered dangerous. As @harrymc states, there are excellent, free programs such as qBittorent , https://www.qbittorrent.org/ , which not only pass MS muster, but are also available as "apps" through their store.

Comment: Downloading latest version of utorrent proved impossible as Windows blocked access to the download sites, marking them as insecure. However, I was able to download and install qbittorrent, and it is functioning satisfactorily. Thanks @harrymc & DrMoishe Pippik

Answer (score 0):

To sum up this thread :

The poster had problems with Windows Defender totally refusing to run
utorrent.

The solution was to use another bittorrent client, in this case
[qBittorrent](https://www.qbittorrent.org/).

Answer (score 0):

It is quite well possible to configure the windows defender to stop blocking utorrent.

Here are the pictures:

1. select Virus & threat protection
   [image: select Virus & threat protection]
2. Choose *manage settings*  and then scroll down to Exclusions.
   [image: manage settings]
3. Add the exclusions as in the picture below.
   [image: add the exclusions as in the picture below]

**Note**: Notice that utorrent.exe is also added as a process exclusion.